# Restrict FileDialog folders

Tags: qt, qml, filedialog

I'm using QtQuick Dialogs 1.2 in Qt application over Linux and I want to restrict my FileDialog to just two paths specified by me. My FileDialog is something like that:

```
FileDialog {
    id: fileDialogExample
    title: qsTr("File Dialog example")
    nameFilters: [qsTr("Image files %1").arg("(*.jpg *.png)")]
    folder: '/home/user/Downloads'
}
```

I want my file dialog only accept jpg/png files and start in specified path, but can move only to /mnt. Is this possible with stock FileDialog in Qt Dialogs 1.2?

Answer (score 0):

Documentation does not mention allowing specific directories. What I have done in similar case was something like this:

```
FileDialog {
    onFolderChanged: {
        if (/* folder not allowed */)
            folder = /* closest allowed dir */  // does not do anything with stock FileDialog
    }
}
```

Unfortunately this does not work with stock `FileDialog`. I have been using custom component and I had full control of it. I think that it is not possible to do what you need with current `FileDialog`. Of course you can close the dialog when user opens unwanted folder and then reopen it with correct path but I would not recommend it.